# When should cross country flights occur in flight training

Tags: flight-training

Question about 141 flight schools.  I'm 52 hours into flight training and my 141 flight school wants me to do my cross country work prior to a maneuvering stage check, landing stage check and solo endorsement.

Is this a red flag, meaning the school is milking me for my money?

My understanding is there are two 50 NM flights and 150 NM flight that occurs with instructor and then need to be completed individually.

Monetarily  I want to know that I'm endorsed to fly solo before spending the money on the dual cross country.

My school is unwilling to endorse Solo flight until I have fulfilled cross wind landings with winds at 15 knots.

Thank you

Comment: Red flag about the school? Or about your current training level?

Comment: Please be more specific. I want to edit the title so that it looks like a question but I find hard to guess what you are asking for (is it normal to make cross country flight with 50 flight hours? at what time should first cross country occur? what kind of flight test a flight school is able perform prior to endorsement?) As is, your question seems really broad and unspecific.

Answer (score 1):

There is no prescribed threshold to cross that indicates when XC training should start.

I generally wait until after a student's first solo to start talking about cross country work.  The first solo is a massive psychological barrier and once the student realizes that they **really can** fly a plane by themselves, it gives them confidence to learn new stuff.

That said, you are at a 141 school.  They need to follow their approved training schedule.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  They do not seem to be following the approved training schedule.  I'm going to follow up with the FAA.

Comment: @ubah NO.  DON'T DO THAT YET.  Talk to your instructor's boss, then that guy's boss.  DO NOT jump straight to the FAA.  They are not there to help you and you may end up worse off when you have to start over with a new school.

Comment: Yes, going to the FAA will red flag you as a student!

Comment: Ok.  I'll bail on that.  I already spoke to the chief flight instructor who is married to the owner.  Have an app the records all calls.  It was very professional, maintained a positive attitude throughout.  The sales pitch was just awful.  Basic message was stick to the program, fly my cross country without the manuever and landing stage checks.  And without the solo endorsement, which will be based on cross wind landings with 15 knot winds.....meet with a different school tomorrow.

Comment: It seems that you already have a very contentious relationship with the school.  Good luck.  FYI, recording a phone conversation without the consent of the other party is illegal in many states.

Comment: Its only illegal if i publish it.  If the judge doesn't know it happened then its not a crime.

Comment: I'm sure your next school will be lucky to have you as a student.

Comment: We can close this.  I got the answer I was looking for.  Need to get the school to follow the approved training program.  Since they have deviated I plan on leaving.  Thank you for the input.